# Trouble with installing TDM-GCC/OpenBLAS for Theano on Windows 10 - DLL load failed

Tags: gcc, theano, openblas

Without using a C++ compiler my setup (see below) works well (but slow of course).
To speed up the runtime I tried to install TDM-GCC. Then the import error "DLL load failed" was shown.
After spending hours to read installation guides, downloading OpenBLAS, experiment, read question/comments to "DLL load failed" - I came no step forward.
Can anyone help me?

Installed software:

- Windows 10 Home
- Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- numpy (1.13.0rc2+mkl) (installed as wheel)
- scipy (0.19.0)            (installed as wheel)
- scikit-learn (0.18.1) (installed as wheel)
- Theano (0.9.0)
- Keras (2.0.6)
- gcc version 5.1.0 (tdm64-1)
- OpenBLAS-v0.2.19-Win64-int32

I added the following entries to the path:

```
C:\Python36\
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin\
C:\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\
C:\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\
C:\TDM-GCC-64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\5.1.0\
C:\TDM-GCC-64\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\5.1.0\
C:\OpenBLAS-v0.2.19-Win64-int32\bin\
C:\OpenBLAS-v0.2.19-Win64-int32\lib\
```

My theaonrc.txt looks like this:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = cpu
cxx=C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\g++.exe

[blas]
ldflags = -LC:\\OpenBLAS-v0.2.19-Win64-int32\\bin -LC:\\OpenBLAS-v0.2.19-  Win64-int32\\lib -lopenblas
```

Error log:

```
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.gof.compilelock): Overriding existing lock by dead process '1004' (I am process '6472')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Christian/Python/DL.py", line 15, in <module>
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 436, in add
layer(x)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 569, in __call__
self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\core.py", line 825, in build
constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 391, in add_weight
weight = K.variable(initializer(shape), dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers.py", line 208, in __call__
dtype=dtype, seed=self.seed)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 2191, in random_uniform
return rng.uniform(shape, low=minval, high=maxval, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py", line 1354, in uniform
rstates = self.get_substream_rstates(nstreams, dtype)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\configparser.py", line 117, in res
return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py", line 1256, in get_substream_rstates
multMatVect(rval[0], A1p72, M1, A2p72, M2)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\sandbox\rng_mrg.py", line 66, in multMatVect
[A_sym, s_sym, m_sym, A2_sym, s2_sym, m2_sym], o, profile=False)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function.py", line 326, in function
output_keys=output_keys)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\pfunc.py", line 486, in pfunc
output_keys=output_keys)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1795, in orig_function
defaults)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1661, in create
input_storage=input_storage_lists, storage_map=storage_map)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 699, in make_thunk
storage_map=storage_map)[:3]
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 1047, in make_all
impl=impl))
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 935, in make_thunk
no_recycling)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 839, in make_c_thunk
output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1190, in make_thunk
keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1131, in __compile__
keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1586, in cthunk_factory
key=key, lnk=self, keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1159, in module_from_key
module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1489, in compile_cmodule
preargs=preargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2325, in compile_str
return dlimport(lib_filename)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 302, in dlimport
rval = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, [module_name])
ImportError: DLL load failed: Eine DLL-Initialisierungsroutine ist fehlgeschlagen.
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, uninstalled my setup and installed Anaconda – now it works :-)

For installing Anaconda I used the guide https://machinelearningmastery.com/setup-python-environment-machine-learning-deep-learning-anaconda/